# Date and Time Picker, what is the best (and simple) solution?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-datepicker

I need a simple and fast way to accept a full date (with hour and minute) from the user of my app. What I should use? I had considered Date and Time Picker but both use to much space in my activity's layout... Thank you. Jefferson

Comment: you can use date and time picker dialog.  see the example http://www.journaldev.com/9976/android-date-and-time-picker-dialog-example-tutorial

Comment: Thank you [Ankur1994a](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4563338/ankur1994a), I found a elegant solution just following your link.

Comment: Welcome,  please vote up my comment to get me points,  if you thinks its useful to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the example that [Ankur1994a](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4563338/ankur1994a) gave, I made a simple method that responds to a click event on a imageButton. This method creates a DatePicker Dialog e then, after user's pick, creates a Time Picker. Simple and efficient.

```
public void escolheDataHoraInicio(View v) {

    // Pega a data e hora corrente
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    Integer mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);;
    Integer mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    Integer mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ProvaNovaActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                String _data = dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year;
                _lblDataHoraInicio.setText(_data);
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(ProvaNovaActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        String _dataHora = _lblDataHoraInicio.getText().toString() + " " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
                        _lblDataHoraInicio.setText(_dataHora);
                    }
                }, 0, 0, false);
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering your headline-question:
There is an android-library: [better pickers](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers). Easy to implement. Time-picker looks like this:

[image: TimePicker from better pickers]

> I had considered Date and Time Picker but both use to much space in my activity's layout

It's a dialog, so it should have nothing to do with your activity-layout (or did I misunderstand you?).

Hope I could help you :)

Comment: [Micha F.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5433102/micha-f), I was putting the Pickers INSIDE the Activitys layout. Dumb, I know. This is VB6's development craze yet. Thank you anyway.